# Uniform convergence of series of function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a non zero function such that $|f(x)|\leq\frac{1}{1+2x^{2}},x\in\mathbb{R}.$ Define real values functions $f_{n}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by $f_{n}(x)=f(x+n).$ Then the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$ converges uniformy

$A.$ On $[0,1]$ but not on $[-1,0].$

$B.$ On $[-1,0]$ but not on $[0,1].$

$C.$ On  both $[0,1]$ and $[-1,0].$

$D.$ Neither on $[0,1]$ nor on $[-1,0].$

I check that by $M_{n}$ test series is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ as $|f_{x}|\leq\frac{1}{1+2(x+n)^{2}}\leq\frac{1}{n^{2}}.$ How to check on $[-1,0]?$ Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $[-1,0], |f_n(x)|\leq {1\over{1+2(x+n)^2}}\leq {1\over (n-1)^2}$